# VB.NET: How to check input if it is existing in the Dataset before adding

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I need to check the user input before it is inserted in the dataset.
here is my code.

```
           If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                foundRows = ds.Tables(0).Select("AccessionNumber = '" + txtaccn.Text + "'")
            End If

            If book.checkifaccnexist(txtaccn.Text) = 1 Then
                If foundRows Is Nothing Then
                    dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {txtaccn.Text})
                    acn = acn.Insert(acn.Length, (" OR accn = '" + Label1.Text + "'"))
                    txtaccn.Clear()

                Else
                    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "The accession number you've inputed is already in the list", "Library Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                    txtaccn.Clear()
                End If
            Else

                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Accession Number Doesn't exist", "Library Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                txtaccn.Clear()
            End If
```

The problem with this code is even though I input different number in txtaccn.text, **foundRows**

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with the line

```
If foundRows Is Nothing Then
```

Maybe trying this might help,

```
If foundRows.Length = 0 Then
'Add to DataTable
```

Comment: I tried it but it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Select expressions return array of DataRows. Please make sure that foundRows is declared as DataRows, and accessible. Also the select expressions seems to have filtering the AccessionNumber as String. Is AccessionNumber a text datatype in the Dataset?

Comment: foundRows is already declared. Yes AccessionNumber is declared as string

Comment: Is it showing the error, The accession number you've inputed is already in the list? Please insert breakpoint on the first statement and make sure if the foundRows length is more than 0 for an existing acn. I'm sry i cant be of much help.